# Dynamically import and render an SVG image with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, dynamic, components

I'm trying to dynamically render SVG images from the react-icons SVG library.

This is a component that is to be rendered multiple times on the page each with a different passed string referencing an SVG filename in the react-icons library.

I'd like to import and render the SVG file based on the matching filename string for each SVG which is located in `averageWeather.weather[0].icon`.

`averageWeather.weather[0].icon` === `'svgFileName'`

I need to:

1. Find a way of importing the entire WI library in a way that I can extract a single file with the string in `averageWeather.weather[0].icon`.
2. Redner that extracted file in JSX.

I *could* import all of my required images individually like so:

`import { SVGimg1, SVGimg2, SVGimg3, SVGimg4, etc, etc } from 'react-icons/wi'`

But surely there's a better way than this? I'd rather not do this as I need to access many possible images which will undoubtedly grow in the future.

My best attempt at the moment:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as classes from './WeatherIcon.module.scss'
import { findMostFrequent } from '../../../shared/weather'
import * as SVG from 'react-icons/wi'

const WeatherIcon = props => {
  const averageWeather = findMostFrequent(props.list)

  return (
  <div className={classes.WeatherIcon}>
    <SVG.{averageWeather.weather[0].icon} />
  </div>
  )
}

export default WeatherIcon
```

`findMostFrequent(props.list)` returns an object containing the filename I need.

This is what I wish to be possible:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as classes from './WeatherIcon.module.scss'
import { findMostFrequent } from '../../../shared/weather'

const WeatherIcon = props => {
  const averageWeather = findMostFrequent(props.list)
  const {averageWeather.weather[0].icon} = require('react-icons/wi')

  return (
  <div className={classes.WeatherIcon}>
    <{averageWeather.weather[0].icon}/>
  </div>
  )
}

export default WeatherIcon
```

I have tried `const reqSvgs = require.context('react-icons/wi', true, /\.svg$/)`.
I get this error when I try this:

```
webpackEmptyContext(req) {
    var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
    e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
    throw e;
}
```

Is this possible?